# Scroll to the bottom after render a Backbone view

Tags: scroll, backbone-views

I'm currently working on a messaging system using Backbone. I want to scroll to the last element in a CollectionView on render.

I can get this to work after clicking on link on the page, but I want it to happen on the render of the view.

Here's what I'm using in the link, which works:

```
document.getElementById('message-new-conversation-dialog').scrollIntoView();
```

Here's the view definition:

```
var ConversationView = LSmixBB.CollectionView.extend({

        itemView: MessageView,
        template: "#message-conversation-template",
        onRender: function(){
            document.getElementById('message-new-conversation-dialog').scrollIntoView();
            document.getElementById('global-column-middle-footer1').scrollIntoView();
        }

    });
```

I presume it doesn't work because there's nothing on the page inside onRender?

I am very new to web development, so be gentle!

Anyway, I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Backbone you have access to Underscore's _defer function: http://underscorejs.org/#defer

This will wait until all the DOM manipulations are done and then the function will execute, if you need an internal reference to caller, you can pass `this` in

```
_.defer(function(caller){
      //caller is now a reference to the scope where you declared this
}, this);
```

I use this when I have views that need to create child views asynchronously, but those child views need the parent view to be rendered and in the DOM. If you have full control over the child views then it might be better to have some type of callback though.

> Note: you can also use jQuery's .ready function on elements too, but I
>   haven't played with that yet, though it might be a better solution in
>   some cases, since _defer basically waits till the call stack is done
>   executing

Comment: Careful though, don't use this unless **you absolutely have to**, usually simple DOM manipulations are synchronous so subsequent code can assume the DOM is rendered completely. But in some cases, I think yours including, there are asynchronous renders happening.

Comment: Ok, yes, good point. I am loading in a collection from an AJAX call, after loaded I want to scroll to the end. So far _.defer has been working for me for this purpose. For this question, your answer is correct. Cheers!

Comment: Could you not put the scroll to the end in the callback handler from the AJAX collection load call?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone finds this useful, I ended up using a timeout, which worked. So, you can write a function that uses scrollIntoView but have a delay of say 200ms to run that to allow the page to render.

Because I was rendering a collection inside this view, the items weren't rendered in onRender.

There's probably a better way to do this, but so far I haven't found one as yet!